# CSS and Jquery: Avoid breaking top z-index when using social network buttons

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, facebook-social-plugins

So, I have several popups on my website. When the user click on some of them or opens a new one, of course this should come on the top.
I am using the [TopZIndex jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TopZIndex) to calculate the highest z-index and set it to the selected window. However, I have a problem. Whenever I try to add buttons for social networks, since the facebook button uses iframe, the topZIndex always returns the iframe z-index value. Because of that, every time topZIndex() is called when clicking on the popup I get the same z-index, and the popup does not get on top because of that.

Since (as far as I understood), I cannot have the facebook like button without iframes, what can I do to avoid this problem with topZIndex()?
I tried to rewrite the function to get the highest z-index as well, but the result is the same.

Comment: why not just set the z-index to something absurdly high, like 10000?  Surely no other regular element will have this value.

Comment: That does not solve the problem, even if I don’t undestand why. The problem depends on topZIndex taking the value from iframe, whatever that is. So, for example: iframe has z-index 2000; popupA has 1; and popupB has 2; I click on popupA and it appears (get 2001); now, if I click on popupB, that should get this last value and add 1. Instead, it keeps taking 2000, no matter how many times I click on each. So 2000 + 1 is always 2001, and there is no visibile change. If I set popupA to 3000, for example, it keeps recognizing 2000 as top z index.

Comment: I somehow solved the problem, actually. I manually written the code for facebook like button, and the iframe does not give me any problem in this case. At first I have used ShareThis, which gives me the z-index problem. So, in principle all is well now, even if I still do not understand what was going on. I leave the question open, through, since I wouldn’t mind to use ShareThis if possible.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood.  Glad things are solved :)